# Amazon Redshift at 100% disk usage due to DEEP COPY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I was trying to deep copy one of our table which 12.5% of total disk space (25%approx of actual data on the disk). While inserting into the new table (with recommended compression), the query failed with disk usage full error.

How to perform the deep copy on such huge tables without causing any issues?

Comment: please update your question with more details ddl/sql used.

Answer (score 1):

We also ran into the same issue for our stage cluster. When a large RedShift table gets heavily fragmented, attempted deep copy on that table needs to keep the entire table temporarily into memory & disk removing all encoding on that table, then re-encode and sort the table before putting into the new target deep copy table; which needs significant amount of disk space.

We followed below steps to overcome this issue for a 1 tera-byte table, with 80% fragmentation:

1. Create a manual snapshot for back-up & recovery in case of any uncertainty.
2. Resize the cluster to higher size keeping more than four times free memory than the table-size
3. Run deep copy process suspending all other processes and connections from the cluster
4. Create another manual snapshot for back-up & recovery purpose.
5. Resize the cluster back to it's original size

As a best practice, we should always monitor disk fragmentation to be less than 20%.
Below query may be useful to setup as alert to monitor cluster health for table fragmentation and statistics:

```
            SELECT feedback_tbl.schema_name,
               feedback_tbl.table_name, 
               cast(info_tbl."size"/1024 AS varchar(10)) + ' GB' table_size,
               coalesce(unsorted :: varchar(10),'null') + '%' fragment_pct, stats_off :: varchar(10) stale_stat_pct
            FROM (SELECT schema_name, table_name
                  FROM (SELECT TRIM(n.nspname) schema_name,
                               TRIM(c.relname) table_name,
                               DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS qry_rnk,
                               COUNT(*)
                          FROM stl_alert_event_log AS l
                          JOIN (SELECT query, tbl, perm_table_name
                                 FROM stl_scan
                                WHERE perm_table_name <> 'Internal Worktable'
                                GROUP BY query, tbl, perm_table_name) AS s
                            ON s.query = l.query
                          JOIN pg_class c
                            ON c.oid = s.tbl
                          JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
                            ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
                         WHERE l.userid > 1
                           AND l.event_time >= dateadd(DAY, -7, CURRENT_DATE)
                           AND regexp_instr(solution, '.*VACUUM.*reclaim deleted.') > 0
                           and TRIM(n.nspname)='ivh'
                         GROUP BY TRIM(n.nspname), TRIM(c.relname)
                         ) anlyz_tbl
                 WHERE anlyz_tbl.qry_rnk < 25) feedback_tbl
            JOIN svv_table_info info_tbl
            ON info_tbl.schema = feedback_tbl.schema_name
            AND info_tbl.table = feedback_tbl.table_name
            WHERE (info_tbl.unsorted > 5 OR info_tbl.stats_off > 10)
```

Above SQL was picked from AWS Redshift Analyze Vacuum Utility.

[Redshift Analyze Vacuum Utility](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/AnalyzeVacuumUtility)